# Adding a header image before navbar-fixed-top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I add a header image so that it will appear on top of a navbar-fixed-top. And as the user scrolls down the navbar will stick to the top?

I have tried adding it to a container but it does not work as expected.

Here is my code so far.

```
<body>
 <header>
  <img src="header/1024x100.png">
 </header>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#"></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
          Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us some code or a test page ?

Comment: check solution please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsFiddle with scrolling nav [check link](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/YKaBK/show)

Note: Incase your image is smaller than screen size,insert this snippet inside your css

```
.masthead img{
width:100%;
 }
```

The html should look like the following :

```
<div class="masthead">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x150"/>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<div class="navbar affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
               <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- navbar -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
    content goes here 
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Shail, it's not really smooth scrolling.

Comment: @JohnDoe Buddy You didnt asked for it .As per your original request you wanted to place header image on top of navigation . And I think my solution does that , isnt it ? regarding the scrolling .. you get smooth scroll by adding jquery