# Adding affix to a navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to get my Navbar affixed to the top of the page after I have scrolled past an image. I have tried following the solutions from [How to Add Affix to Bootstrap Fixed Bottom Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770895/how-to-add-affix-to-bootstrap-fixed-bottom-navbar) and [Adding a header image before navbar-fixed-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105018/adding-a-header-image-before-navbar-fixed-top), however, I can't seem to get the Navbar to stay on the screen.

My HTML code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" data-spy="affix" 
data-offset-top="50">
```

and my CSS is:

```
.affix {
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
}

.affix-top {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Bootstrap and JQuery I have imported:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help you can provide would be great

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you gone through https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: I have, yes. Their example 1 is exactly what I am trying to do ... but I am just failing at it

Comment: You need to have javascript or jQuery for this. Where is your's?

Comment: @Ramesh I have edited the question showing what it is I am importing ... is this what you meant?

The only difference I can tell between mine and the w3schools example is that I am using a newer version of bootstrap

If I change my bootstrap to the older version it works ... But I feel this is a shoddy work around

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has few conflicts with bootstrap 3 and older. You can clearly see the difference between them here : https://blog.templatetoaster.com/bootstrap-3-vs-bootstrap-4-migrate-differences/.   I recommend you to use bootstrap 3 if you are not familiar with bootstrap 4

Comment: I just read that comment after I posted that "answer" that I posted. Thank you for your help ... I'm going to try and leave them both in and hope that nothing I have conflicts; it's only a simple website. Thanks again @Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Right ... so after a little longer of searching, I have finally realised what the problem was ... I was following the Bootstrap 4 tutorial until I wanted the sticky nav bar. Then I accidentally clicked on the link for Bootstrap 3 without realising.

To get a nav bar sticky in Bootstrap 4, you just need to add "sticky-top" to the nav class like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
```

Comment: Better to use only `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. Don't use both version at once.

Comment: I've edited the answer now. I realised my mistake, I can't believe it was something so small